# My responsive work in local but not when it's on the server

Tags: css

I work as an intern on a website wich is actually protected with pass so I can't give you the link...

Anyway, I will ask the question and if you need some code I can give it.

So, there is a responsive design for the mobile made buy an external party which created the design/css. The responsive work correctly when I work with wampServer, and I resized the page with the ctrl+maj+m on firefox.

The actual problem is, when I put the same page on the server, the responsive don't work anymore... on firefox and on mobile phones.

I don't get how is that possible, so maybe someone encountered the same problem and has some tips?

Thank you

**EDIT** : There is ONE page which still works online, but I really don't get why, it has exactly the same code as the others... the 'responsive code' is included in each page at the top with the footer too (but this one is at the end of the page). Just the body changes on every page.

EDIT EDIT :

Here is the sample code. [header.php](http://pastebin.com/MgTfPwXa), [head.php](http://pastebin.com/69imRQ21), [mainmenu.php](http://pastebin.com/ZxdRzyGU).

EDIT OF THE MASTER EDIT :

Thanks Abdul-Rafay Shaikh.

Well, all of the css is imported in the import `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/zz-all.css" type="text/css" />`. Which is called in the head.php. The path is good, in fact it works in one page and not the others. I think I have to check, line by line, all of the code to find maybe an import that f***ed all up, or something like that.

Thanks for all your help anyway :)

Comment: no code? seriously? try to remake the problem in similar or smaller code

Comment: Do you have a <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" /> or similar tag in your document's <head>? If so, could we see it? If not, add the one above and you should be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think the responsive template you are using maybe used javascript to actually make breakpoints and as you told us that the one page that is working when deployed on a real server has the responsive css in the footer. So my solution would be put the css of all the pages in the footer or check wether any js is actually making the breakpoint and put the CSS after that javascript.

The Second thing is the path's maybe your CSS that has the responsive code has their path defined preceding localhost/ or some thing like that check that.

Third if there is no javascript that is making your website responsive and its only css import your responsive CSS to the main stylesheet

In your main style sheet

```
@import url("responsive.css");
```

just to make sure that your responsive style sheet is loaded whenever your main style sheet is loaded.

I hope this solves the problem